# How to us htaccess rewrite-rules to change URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how can i convert a URI like

```
"www.mydomain.org/index.php?detail=This is my product name"
```

to

```
"www.mydomain.org/product/this-is-my-product-name"?
```

using mod_rewrite and rewrite-rules?

Is there any way to get this working? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just why do you want to do it in .htaccess when you're anyway getting GET parameter in `index.php` where you could do a simple `str_replace`.

Answer (score 0):

put the following in your htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/?$ /index.php?detail=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it's not working. Maybe I was wrong with my explanation. The URL http://www.example.com/product/this-is-my-product should be a server sided www.example.com/index.php?detail=This is my product name 

Is this possible?